# Unable to get previous_post_link to work

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to fetch previous and next custom post type link from same taxonomy within single-custom-post-type file

As per codex passing 5th parameter i.e. taxonomy name http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_post_link should make it work

Here is my code

```
previous_post_link('%link', 'Previous Case', TRUE,'',$taxonomy)
previous_post_link('%link', 'Previous Case', TRUE,'','custom_categories')
```

I have tried both way i.e. passing dynamic variable as well as string, yet I cannot get it to work, What it returns is random custom post type links rather than from same category

the code is bit long so I have pasted it over pastebin http://pastebin.com/X5pKuifA

Comment: Is your taxonomy 'custom_category' or 'custom_categories'?

Comment: It's custom_categories

Comment: Even If I remove all the code and keep the required one I am having the same issue ...
only required code http://pastebin.com/eMg7KcuK

Answer (score 0):

The above code works perfectly as mentioned in codex, The issue turns out to be I have allocated 2 categories mistakenly to all of the custom post type thus the pagination within same taxonomy was not working.
So If you land on this question make sure you donot have more than 1 category assigned to your posts